# Load large files to Amazon S3

Tags: linux, amazon-s3

I am using a linux machine and I would like to upload 12GB file to s3.

While using the web console I got the message that the browser support only files smaller than 1.9 GB.

What are the options for loading such a big file?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better in the http://serverfault.com/ companion site?

Comment: There should be something called "Multipart Upload feature" to upload bigger files.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html) should support big files (taken from here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html)

Answer (score -2):

Try s3md - http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

If you're on Ubuntu or other linux,

```
$ sudo apt-get install s3cmd
$ s3cmd --configure

  ....

$ s3cmd put myfile s3://mybucket
```